# scrapoxy: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scrapoxy

I'm trying to run scrapoxy for first time and coming with error. I followed the steps from documentation to copy AMI and I also tried to use AMI in eu-west-1 region but came with same error.

```
2020-10-09T04:47:45.764Z - debug: [Manager] checkInstances
2020-10-09T04:47:46.020Z - debug: [Manager] adjustInstances: required:1 / actual:0
2020-10-09T04:47:46.020Z - debug: [Manager] adjustInstances: add 1 instances
2020-10-09T04:47:46.021Z - debug: [ProviderAWSEC2] createInstances: count=1
2020-10-09T04:47:46.483Z - error: [Manager] Error: Cannot update or adjust instances: message=The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations., stack=Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
    at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/ec2.js:50:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9), code=Unsupported, name=Unsupported, time=Fri Oct 09 2020 10:17:46 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), requestId=56ce525e-eaa0-4690-923c-1f531651d49c, statusCode=400, retryable=false, retryDelay=33.88164667234908
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be because the AMI you copied has no compatible machine type in the region you want to run Scrapoxy.

- eu-west-1 / t1.micro: ami-c74d0db4
- eu-west-1 / t2.micro: ami-485fbba5
- eu-west-1 / t2.nano: ami-06220275

Please refer to the [doc](https://scrapoxy.readthedocs.io/en/master/standard/providers/awsec2/index.html#step-4-choose-an-ami), and verify the region you want to run Scrapoxy has the machine type available.